# I want to improve my SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table (table1) and it has 2 columns **id** and **name** and below are the data in the table.

> ---- INPUT TABLE ---

```
id   name
 1  |  ABC
 2  |  XYZ
 3  |  DEF
```

I want write SQL which will give **output** as mentioned below

Columns of output are **id**,**col1**,**col2** and **col3** and below are the values expected in the columns

> 1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
>
> 2 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
>
> 3 FALSE FALSE TRUE

Now I want to write a SQL based on the above output.

I have written one SQL using CASE statement withing SQL but I know there should be a better way to write this SQL and get the output.

My SQL :

```
select id, CASE WHEN NAME ='XYZ' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS colTRUE ,FALSE as col2,FALSE as col3 from tabel1
union all
select id, FALSE AS col1 ,CASE WHEN NAME ='XYZ' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END as col2,FALSE as col3 from tabel1
union all
select id, FALSE AS col1 ,FALSE as col2,CASE WHEN NAME ='DEF' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END col3 from tabel1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.id, t1.id = t.id, t2.id = t.id, t3.id = t.id
FROM table t, table t1, table t2, table t3
WHERE t1.id != t2.id
  AND t2.id != t3.id
  AND t1.id != t3.id
```

Answer (score 1):

A CASE statement is your best tool for this situation.  Sometimes you just have to go with your first hunch.  However you do not need the union all operator, just use each CASE statement as a single value in your SELECT statement.

Comment: AS suggested I got rid of the union and that was a good suggestion.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for but I'm not sure why.

```
select 
  id, 
  CASE WHEN NAME ='ABC' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS col,
  CASE WHEN NAME ='XYZ' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS col2,
  CASE WHEN NAME ='DEF' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS col3 
from tabel1
```

Comment: Yes this does solve but was looking for a simpler option if any becasue for my real work there are around 25 columns I have to apply this CASE statements.

Comment: @Vikram -- just write an SQL statement to write your SQL statement